# postgis function in graphql/hasura

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgis, hasura

I'm new to graphql/hasura. I want to run the following raw sql in hasura through `mutation`:

```
update features
set feature = st_translate(feature, 150,30);
```

This sql translates the whole `feature` column in table `features`.
It seems this is not achievable through `mutation`? Mainly because `st_translate` is a function which cannot be used in the hasura query `_set:feature{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by using run_sql to post raw sql.